# Show that $f(z)=\log(z + 3i)$ has an inverse function where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand why the domain is $\mathbb C\backslash\{-3i\}$ but not sure how to go about showing an inverse exists.  Surely it's just $e^{z+3i}$? I don't really understand how logarithms work in the complex plane.

Comment: you mean $e^z - 3i$?

Comment: I don't know... what confuses me is that e^(z) is not a one-one function if z is complex so I don't really know what the inverse of a logarithmic function will be

Comment: You have to look at a branch of $e^z$ where it is one-one. see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function

Answer (score 0):

hint $log(z)=ln(z)+iargZ=ln(z)+i\theta$ here if we assume $z=x+iy$ then it becomes $log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+9})+itan^{-1}(\frac{y+3}{x})$ note $\tan$ depends on the quadrant in which  the $\theta$ lies.

Comment: thanks I think that's the hint I needed.  Am i correct in saying that for a general function Log(z), it's image is {w: -pi<Imw<pi}?

Comment: ya image rotates on axis by $\theta=\pi^c$(rads) eg $i,-i$  one is on positive   y axis and other on negative thus $\theta=180$